# How to move the top panel in ios app

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

My app top bar very stretched on iPhone and and closes the status bar. How to fix it? On iPhone simulator there is no such it
[image: ios simulator]

[image: iphone]

Comment: Show us some code or Storyboards screenshots/info maybe?

Comment: @Neeku,the fact that I got a project without storyboard file((

Comment: Then showing the code is the right option, if the provided answers aren't helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in info.plist add `View controller-based status bar appearance` property and set `NO`

[image: info.plist]

in project `General` settings set status bar `hide during application launch`
[image: project properties]

Answer (score 1):

At Project General setting, you just check it

[image]